# Time Complexity for binary permutation representation of n bits

Tags: java, algorithm, time, time-complexity

I have return a below code in java to produce the possible binary representation of n digits.

```
public List<String> binaryRepresenation(int n){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(n>0){
        permuation(n, list, "");
    }
    return list;
}

private void permuation(int n, List<String> list, String str){
    if(n==0){
        list.add(str);
    }else{
        permuation(n-1, list, str+"0");
        permuation(n-1, list, str+"1");
    }
}
```

For n=3, it produces 001 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 combinations. 
Overall this function produces 2^n possible representations.

Is it safe to say the time complexity is n * 2^n

Where 2^n time the method is called for base cases. In order to reach the each base case, it would have called the permutation method for maximum of n times.

So overall upper bound time complexity is n*2^n? Kindly correct me if i am wrong. I came to this conclusion based on the string permutation time complexity discussed in this thread [Time Complexity of Permutations of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067983/time-complexity-of-permutations-of-a-string) . Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Time Complexity : 2^n

Answer (score 2):

There is a small problem with your analysis. As you noticed, for each base case you have to call the function n times. But, some of those calls are being shared by other base cases. In other words, you are counting the same call multiple times.

This means that while the complexity definitely can't be greater than `n * 2 ^ n`, it might actually be lower.

To calculate a better bound on the complexity, you can count the actual number of calls to the `permutation` function. One way to do that is to consider the possible values of the `str` variable.

`str` will be a binary string of length less than or equal to `n`. Also, each call to the `permutation` function receives a unique value of `str`. This implies that the number of times the function is called is equal to the number of binary strings of length <= n.

How many such strings are there? `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2 ^ n = 2 ^ (n + 1) - 1`

So, the number of times `permutation` is called is `O(2^n)`.
But each call includes the operations `str + "0"` and `str + "1"`. These operations take `O(n)` time. So, the net time complexity of the operation is: `O(n * 2^n)` but for somewhat different reasons than you originally thought.

Comment: It would be O(2^n), except that `str+"0"` and `str+"1"` each take O(n) time.   So the complexity really is O(n*2^n), but not for the reason the OP imagines.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is O(2<sup>n</sup>). Each function call pushes two new function calls onto the stack until the base case is reached. Visualize the tree for `n = 3` as follows:

```
            ________""________
           /                  \
       ___0___              ___1___
      /       \            /       \
    _00_     _01_        _10_     _11_
   /    \   /    \      /    \   /    \
  000  001 010   011   100  101 110   111
```

This is a perfect binary tree with 15 nodes and 8 leaves. 2<sup>n+1</sup> states are visited, but we can remove the constant and simplify to O(2<sup>n</sup>).

String concatenation adds an `n` multiplier to the complexity, but using a `StringBuilder` or container with constant-time push/pop or add/remove operations should eliminate this, suggesting that that is only an implementation detail specific to your posted code, and not the algorithm's complexity in general.

Comment: Possibly, but what is your rationale? Your [newly-added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65551535/6243352) is tautological. The only explanation is "In fact, the time complexity stays `ϴ(p^n)` even if you perform any polynomial amount of work in addition to the recursive call" -- but why is this the case? It's counterintuitive that using an O(1) string concatenation would yield the same overall time complexity as a linear concatenation incurred an exponential number of times so there would need to be a compelling rationale for disregarding it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add to your answer. I don't have the mathematical background to understand your proof, but it still seems like you're making a leap by saying effectively "there's a general form and we can simply drop the polynomial work just because we can" before even starting the proof. I want to believe because you clearly have more background in this than I do, but I'm not seeing it.